# Java wait notify - notify notifies all threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two classes that extend Thread and a wait/notify

```
class A extends Thread {

    int r = 20;

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}

class B extends Thread {

    A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (a) {
            System.out.println("Starting...");
            try {
                a.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Result is: " + a.r);
        }
    }
}
```

Class A notifies Class B upon end of execution

```
A a = new A();
new B(a).start();
new B(a).start();
new B(a).start();
```

And the following code

```
a.start();
```

Notifies all threads

```
new Thread(a).start();
```

Notifies one thread

Why does a.start() notify all threads?

Comment: Why use such lowlevel primitives when java.util.concurrent has plenty of tools you can use?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis answered your question, but as a side note:  You should be aware that `foo.wait()` is allowed to return even when `foo` has not been notified.  That's called a _spurious wakeup_. You should always call `foo.wait()` in a loop, and keep looping until the event that you are waiting for has definitely happened.

Comment: @jameslarge do you mean something like: while(condition){ foo.wait() } where condition maybe a check for the result?

Comment: @fge i know for concurrent lib i read to give a Java Certification both topics are cover in the book Threads and Concurrency and mentions that  java.util.concurrent is a better approach to Multithreading, thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and any code that changes `condition` should be in a `synchronized(foo)` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not

```
a.start();
```

that notifies all threads. It's the fact that the thread referenced by `a` terminates that notifies all threads waiting on its monitor.

This is explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

> As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. **It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.**

On the other hand, in

```
new Thread(a).start();
```

you're using `a` as a `Runnable`, not as a `Thread`. The actual thread that will invoke `this.notifyAll` is the one created by the instance creation expression `new Thread(a)`, which no other thread has called `Object#wait()` on.